# Is there a good way in Python to create containers for constants

Tags: python, class, static

I am looking for a pythonic way to represent containers of constants.  The constants are accessed as attributes so that the IDE can auto-complete as necessary.
Currently I use simple classes with class attributes:

```
class CONFIG():
    DIR = 'C:'
    VERSION = '2.0'

# usage:
version = CONFIG.VERSION
```

The class is used as an object, never instantiated, the constants are *static* class attributes.  Of course, they can be *messed* with, and that's one problem.

Is there a better way to do this? NamedTuples do not have the flexibility and clarity to add new constants on the fly, unless I miss something.

Background:
My workflow is jupyter notebook -> python script -> library module.
At target, the namespacing is provided by modules or more advanced classes that read configuration files, for example.
Before that, I look for a simple way to namespace my *constants* in the same module or notebook.  For clarity, I use different namespaces for different types of constants, e.g. CONFIG for configuration and PARAMS for parameters of the data model.

Comment: why do you even need a class ```CPNFIG``` when all values are static. you should just ```DIR = 'C:'```

Comment: I would say using Python classes purely for the purpose of namespacing would be considered an antipattern by some, me included.

Use a separate file for constants if you need namespacing, but honestly... I would probably think twice about it. Most of the time it doesn't make sense to introduce a separate namespace just for constants.

Comment: I share the oppinion of @JanLikar, but maybe if you provide some more information we will be able to help you better, because right now it seems that we're overgeneralize your problem.If you have a bunch of variables it would be a good idea to set them in a module, but i would think twice about it.

Comment: Your IDE should be able to autocomplete straight constant definitions `VERSION = "2.0"` regardless of whether they're in a class or just put at the top of the file, where they usually live.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned with the values being overwritten at some point in your code base, you could try using a class property.

```py
class Config:
    @classmethod
    @property
    def dir(cls) -> str:
        return "C://"
```

This cannot be overwritten accidentally and your IDE will help you with autocompletion. However, it is rather verbose code.

Answer (score -1):

[not really an answer]

**When you should use configs class.**
lets have the following example.

```
class Game:

    CRICKET = 1
    FOOTBALL = 2
    BADMINTON = 3
    TENNIS = 4
    VOLLEYBALL = 5

    GAME_CHOICES = (
        (CRICKET, 'Cricket'),
        (FOOTBALL, 'Football'),
        (BADMINTON, 'Badminton'),
        (TENNIS, 'Tennis'),
        (VOLLEYBALL, 'Volleyball'),
    )

print(Game.CRICKET) #1
```

such structure comes handy when you have sort of choices to do something. such as there could be a field in your DB model that you would like to give a choice. you can add following in model class

```
 game_choice = models.IntegerField(
        choices=GAME_CHOICES, default=CRICKET, db_index=True)
```